# Set of all factors of regular language regular?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata, regular-language, finite-automata

If $L$ is a regular language (i.e. acceptable by a finite automata), is the the set of its factors (infixes) also regular?

Comment: What is your intuition? My gut tells me yes.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to prove it by adding edges to the finite automaton that accepted the original language so that it now accepts all the infixes?

Comment: My intuition tells me yes, but as this result is nowhere written (at least I cannot find it) it might be wrong. I guess the following will work: Given an automata for $L$, declare all states final which are on a path from which some final state could be reached, then add $\varepsilon$-transition from the start state to each (possible new) final state. I think this would work, but as I said I am not sure.

Comment: OK, would a simple inductive proof (using the inductive formal definition of a regular language) work? That is, use the formal definition found on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language.

Comment: I tried a sketch proof and I think it should go through if you can show prefix & suffix closure of regular languages, which I think is easy to show- or is it already a known result?

Comment: Yes. This is known. To make my argument more formal denote by $T(L)$ the set of all factors, by $A(L)$ all prefixes and by $S(L)$ all suffixes. Now the induction. Suppose $U$ is a finite language, then $T(L)$ is finite too, hence regular. Now suppose $U$ and $V$ are regular languages, and we assume by induction that $T(U)$ and $T(V)$ are regular. Now the induction step for i) union: $T(U\cup V) = T(U)\cup T(V)$, regular as union of regular lang. ii) concatenation: $T(UV) = T(U)\cup T(V)\cup S(U)\cdot A(V)$ which is regular, iii) star: $T(U^*)=S(U)U^* A(U)\cup T(U)$ is regular. Am i right?

Comment: I think so. Seems both intuitive and clear. I did out an induction below. Though it would be nice to get an expert on regular languages to look at this just to be sure.

Comment: Yes. Okay, before accepting your anwer I will leave it unaccepted a few days to draw attention of possible experts on this thread ;)

Comment: Agreed. In particular I am not fully happy with the final inductive case. The Kleene-star. I think I'm leaving something out. But I would be very surprised if the result was false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**. This is a consequence of the fact that regular languages are closed under left and right quotients by any language.

Given languages $L$, $X$ and $Y$ of $A^*$, let
$$
X^{-1}LY^{-1} = \{u \in A^* \mid \text{there exist $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ such that $xuy \in L$}\}
$$
I let you verify that $(X^{-1}L)Y^{-1} = X^{-1}(LY^{-1}) = X^{-1}LY^{-1}$ so there is no ambiguity with this notation.

**Theorem**. If $L$ is regular, then $X^{-1}LY^{-1}$ is regular for *any* $X$ and $Y$ (regular or not).

In particular, the set of all factors of $L$, which is equal to
$(A^*)^{-1}L(A^*)^{-1}$, is regular.

**Proof of the theorem**. Observe that
$$
X^{-1}LY^{-1} = \bigcup_{x\in X, y\in Y} x^{-1}Ly^{-1} = \bigcup_{x\in X, y\in Y} (x^{-1}L)y^{-1}
$$
Now if $L$ is regular, 
[Myhill Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) tells you that $L$ has finitely many quotients of the form $x^{-1}L$ and all these quotients are regular. Dually, they are only finitely many quotients of the form $Ly^{-1}$ and finally only finitely many quotients of the form $x^{-1}Ly^{-1}$, all regular again. Since regular languages are closed under finite union, $X^{-1}LY^{-1}$ is regular.

Comment: Excellent answer, giving much insight! After seeing the good proofs here I came up with another, using the algebraic definition: A language $L \subseteq A^*$ is regular iff it there exists a surjective homomorphism $\varphi : A^* \to M$ onto a finite monoid and $P \subseteq M$ such that $L = \varphi^{-1}(P)$. Using this set $P' := \{ \varphi(v) : M \cdot \varphi(v) \cdot M \cap P \ne \emptyset \}$, then $\varphi(v) \in P'$ iff $n\cdot \varphi(v)\cdot m \in P$ for some $m,n$ iff $\varphi(x)\varphi(v)\varphi(y) \in P$ with $n = \varphi(x), m = \varphi(y)$ iff $\varphi(xvy) \in P$ iff $xvy \in L$

Comment: Well, il you know about the syntactic monoid, that's indeed the shortest way (and my favorite, as you may know!).

Comment: Yes, and I like to have these different proofs, one for each famous characterisation of REG, using qotients, using inductive definition and using monoid morphisms (and an automata based sketched in the comments, which should work if written out I guess). Just a proof using MSO-Logic is left to have one for each famous characterisastion of REG :)

Answer (score 2):

We can proceed by induction on the regularity of the language. There are $5$ cases to consider:

- The empty language. Well, in this case, the infixes would also constitute the empty language, which is regular.
- A singleton language. The infixes would constitute just the singleton language again, so we're done here. If the empty string is allowed, then we're still OK because all finite languages are regular.
- For union $A \cup B$, we notice that any term in the language is in either in $A$ or $B$ and we proceed by the inductive hypothesis.
- For concatenation $A . B$ we notice that an infix is either an infix of $A$, an infix of $B$ or a suffix of $A$ and a prefix of $B$. The first two proceed by inductive hypothesis. Since regularity closure is known for prefixes and suffixes, the other case works.
- Finally, for Kleene-star $A^*$, there are $2$ cases to consider. The first is that every infix term is a suffix of $A$, followed by $A^*$, followed by a prefix of $A$. From the known prefix/suffix closures of regular languages, and concatenation, we can combine these into a regular language. For the other case, we have that the infix is an infix of $A$ itself. In this case, we get our result by induction. Then we just use union to put the two cases together into a regular language*.

*This case may need more careful formal treatment than I have given it.